# Python CSV write to file unreadable in Excel (Chinese characters)

Tags: python, excel, csv, unicode

I am trying to performing text analysis on Chinese texts. The program is provided below. I got the result with unreadable characters such as `浜烘皯鏃ユ姤绀捐`. And if I change the output file `result.csv` to `result.txt`, the characters are correct as `人民日报社论`. So what's wrong with this? I can not figure out. I tried several ways including add `decoder` and `encoder`.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import os
    import glob
    import jieba
    import jieba.analyse
    import csv
    import codecs  

    segList = []
    raw_data_path = 'monthly_raw_data/'
    file_name = ["201010", "201011", "201012", "201101", "201103", "201105", "201107", "201109", "201110", "201111", "201112", "201201", "201202", "201203", "201205", "201206", "201208", "201210", "201211"]

    jieba.load_userdict("customized_dict.txt")

    for name in file_name:
        all_text = ""
        multi_line_text = ""
        with open(raw_data_path + name + ".txt", "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                if line != '\n':
                    multi_line_text += line
            templist = multi_line_text.split('\n')
            for text in templist:
                all_text += text
            seg_list = jieba.cut(all_text,cut_all=False)
            temp_text = []
            for item in seg_list:
                temp_text.append(item.encode('utf-8'))

            stop_list = []
            with open("stopwords.txt", "r") as stoplistfile:
                for item in stoplistfile:
                    stop_list.append(item.rstrip('\r\n'))

            text_without_stopwords = []
            for word in temp_text:
                if word not in stop_list:
                    text_without_stopwords.append(word)

            segList.append(text_without_stopwords)


    with open("results/result.csv", 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(segList)
```

Comment: How do you detect the characters are "unreadable" .Do you open the csv-file with Excel? Look into it with a command line tool like  `less`?  Open it with a text editor?

Comment: Yes, I open it with Excel, if I change the file `result.csv` to `result.txt`, I can read all characters. It is very strange.

Comment: Excel has an issue where it mangles special characters. Try opening result.csv in notepad++ for example and see if it's correct.

Comment: I guess the characters are written properly, but excel reads them wrong; by default it assumes the `cp-1252` encoding. I do not have an excel at hand, but can you look around if you can see an option to set the encoding in Excels `Open file ..` dialog? (Or maybe it is called "Import Data" or the like.)

Comment: I've also heard of an issue with the xlsx format to a csv causing this also. The file itself should be fine,  and it seems to be a non easily solved Excel issue.

Comment: @Untitled123, if I open it with notepad, it is correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's just an Excel issue, your files are safe.

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar, there is no option like that.

Comment: @Untitled123, so it is difficult to solve. I think I just output all files as .txt....

Comment: Technically, the csv is not the issue, but rather that Excel is the most common program used to open csv files. From your program's perspective, it really does not matter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For UTF-8 encoding, Excel requires a BOM (byte order mark) codepoint written at the start of the file or it will assume an `ANSI` encoding, which is locale-dependent.  `U+FEFF` is the Unicode BOM.  Here's an example that will open in Excel correctly:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import csv

data = [[u'American', u'美国人'],
        [u'Chinese', u'中国人']]

with open('results.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        w.writerow([item.encode('utf8') for item in row])
```

Python 3 makes this easier.  Use `'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig'` parameters instead of `'wb'`  which will accept Unicode strings directly and automatically write a BOM:

```
#!python3
#coding:utf8
import csv

data = [['American', '美国人'],
        ['Chinese', '中国人']]

with open('results.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerows(data)
```

There is also a 3rd–party `unicodecsv` module that makes Python 2 easier to use as well:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import unicodecsv

data = [[u'American', u'美国人'],
        [u'Chinese', u'中国人']]

with open('results.csv', 'wb') as f:
    w = unicodecsv.writer(f ,encoding='utf-8-sig')
    w.writerows(data)
```

Comment: I got an error using your first code (Python 2.x): `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @flyingmouse, make sure you are encoding Unicode strings and not byte strings.  If you call `.encode('utf8')` on a byte string, Python 2 will do an implicit `.decode('ascii')` to try to turn it into a Unicode string first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way kinda tricky:

```
#!python2
#coding:utf8
import csv

data = [[u'American',u'美国人'],
        [u'Chinese',u'中国人']]

with open('results.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8'))
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        w.writerow([item.encode('utf8') for item in row])
```

This code block generate csv file encoded utf-8 .

1. open file with notepad++ (or other Editor with encode feature)
2. Encoding -> **convert to ANSI**
3. save

Open file with Excel, it's OK.